# How can I set up the proxy for Hazelcast Management Center?

Tags: hazelcast

When I am configuring my hazelcast nodes to connect to the hazelcast management center, when hazelcast is initialized, I see the following stack trace in my hazelcast log file:

```
   2014-08-12 13:19:17,326 [hz.hcMonitorInstanceConfig.MC.State.Sender] DEBUG     - [xt044pdal1.fmr.com]:6301 [testReg-sla-monitor] [3.2.4] Opening collector connection:http://mancenter.xtrac.fmr.com:8080/collector.do
2014-08-12 13:19:22,326 [hz.hcMonitorInstanceConfig.MC.State.Sender] WARN      - [xt044pdal1.fmr.com]:6301 [testReg-sla-monitor] [3.2.4] connect timed out
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:996)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:932)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:850)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1091)
        at com.hazelcast.management.ManagementCenterService$StateSendThread.sendState(ManagementCenterService.java:384)
        at com.hazelcast.management.ManagementCenterService$StateSendThread.run(ManagementCenterService.java:365)
```

this seems to be trouble that the mancenter isn't reachable on port 8080, so I'd like to use the http proxy between the two.  however, when I configure the proxy on tomcat

```
-DproxyHost=<proxyhost> -DproxyPort=<port>
```

I still receive the error.

I tried a curl to that box without the proxy and it fails, but succeeds with the proxy.

How can I set the proxy for connections to the mancenter?

Comment: wondering - have you tried using HA Proxy or squid for the proxy functionality?  I can share config for both (pref ha proxy if needed) - sys admins should be familiar with them specially squid3

Answer (score 0):

That is a good question. The proxyHost and proxyPort are the properties to use to setup a proxy when the HttpURLConnection is used. So I also don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks.  Have you ever tried this in your role at Hazelcast?  I imagine you or others on your time might test for this sort of thing, yes?

Comment: I have not tried it myself. I'll ask one of the guys in charge of the management center to have a look at your question.